# Why is this IIR Filter unstable on the Arduino Due?

Tags: arduino-due, accelerometer, mathematics

I am using an Accelerometer (on the MPU6050) and connected it to the **Arduino Due**. In order to filter the signal I am using an IIR Filter with the following transfer function:

H(z) = Y(z)/X(z) = B/A

B = 0.00000376 + 0.00001127*z^(-1) + 0.00001127*z^(-2) + 0.00000376*z^(-3)

A = 1 - 2.9372*z^(-1) + 2.8763*z^(-2) - 0.9391*z^(-3)

which is an IIR 3th Order Butterworth, Cutoff Freq: 0.5Hz, Samling Freq: 100Hz. These numbers can be calculated by any IIR calculator.

Thus, then discrete equation is:

y[n] = 0.00000376*x[n] + 0.00001127*x[n-1] + 0.00001127*x[n-2] + 0.00000376*x[n-3] + 2.9372*y[n-1] - 2.8763*y[n-2] + 0.9391*y[n-3]

I first tried it on the Arduino UNO. Then I found out that decimal point **precision** (float & double) on the UNO is **only 6-7 digits**. But the therm "B" in the transfer function has for example (0.00000376) **9 digits**. I thought this is the porblem, so I switched to Arduino Due and now I am using double (instead of float) which should have **enough precision**.

It is still unstable. It is not oscillating but getting bigger. I also tried an IIR 4th Order Butterworth, Cutoff Freq: 1Hz, Samling Freq: 100Hz. This one is oscillating.

However, the only IIR that seems to be stable is an IIR 3th Order Butterworth, Cutoff Freq: 1Hz, Samling Freq: 100Hz.

I have no idea so far what the problem is. Could anyone help please?

Comment: Please, post your sketch to begin to work with your question, a set of data to test and the correct results your are expecting.

Answer (score 2):

1. The precision of a float is about 7 **significant** digits. The
   constant term of B in your transfer function (0.00000376) has only 3
   significant digits.
2. Your transfer function has a pole at *z* = 1. It is thus not really
   stable, but only *marginally* stable. Any parasite DC component in
   the input will make the output drift without bounds.

It seems to me that your problem is not related to the implementation of
the filter on the Arduino, but rather to the filter design. Where did
you get that transfer function from?

**Edit**: I looked at the filter you are trying to make. It turns out it
is very sensitive to the precision of the coefficients of A(z). If you
try to add these coefficients, they *almost* cancel out: their sum is
about 3e-5. At zero frequency, both A and B are 3e-5, and the transfer
function, which is their ratio, is 1. By rounding the coefficients to
four decimal places, you made the cancellation exact, and the transfer
function infinite.

Just write the transfer function with more decimal places in the
coefficients and it should work:

H(z) = 3.75592×10<sup>−6</sup> (1 + 3 z<sup>−1</sup> + 3 z<sup>−2</sup> + z<sup>−3</sup>)
         ÷ (1 − 2.9371759 z<sup>−1</sup> + 2.8763097 z<sup>−2</sup> − 0.9391038 z<sup>−3</sup>)

Comment: I used:

https://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html

for the filter. You can use their "in Browser Matlab" for free.

Then you can also use:

https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/roots.html

in order to see that the absolute values of the complex poles are insed the unit circle. Ok so, what am I getting wrong here? :-/

Comment: @user3554669: I don't have a MathWorks account. But you can easily derive the transfer function yourself: Wikipedia provides the continuous-time transfer functions on the page [Butterworth filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterworth_filter). And also a description of the [bilinear transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform), which you can use to derive a discrete-time transfer function.

Comment: That's what I am saying. It should be stable. Poles are inside unit circle.

Comment: @user3554669: No, it is not expected to be stable. For real stability, poles should be in the [interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)) of the unit disc. A pole in the exterior would cause _exponential_ instability. With a pole at _z_ = 1, unbounded _linear_ drift is expected. Note that rounding errors, even at double precision, could put your pole on the exterior.